# Error: pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable

Tags: errors, pdf, compiling

When i write text and $\thetha=5$ in the same line, I get the following error:
--> Error: pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable

If i manually set a new line with \ the file does compile

I already installed cm-super so that is not the problem.
I unistalled MiKTeX and installed it again just to make sure.
I use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} and Texmaker (I also tried Texstudio but that was neither the problem)

Further more my friend can compile the same document I cant.

Comment: you are using a bitmap font somewhere. Remove the microtype package, compile and then look at the end of the log-file. There should be a .pk font somewhere. This should give a clue which font is the problem.

Comment: do you really have `$\thetha=5$` ? that is not a command name that I recognise. Please show a complete small document that generates the error and show the log file from that file.

Comment: it doesnt really matter what command i use.
the error depends on the length of the row.
If the line I write is longer then one row it doesnt compile (if i use mathmatical symobls)

Comment: ! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable
fonts.
<argument> ...shipout:D \box_use:N \l_shipout_box
l.99 \include{./Kapitel/Einleitung}
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
36315 strings out of 479799
769353 string characters out of 2869247
1278139 words of memory out of 3000000
52452 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
567464 words of font info for 105 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
112i,20n,113p,10643b,1180s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
! ==> Fatal error!

Comment: I wrote "REMOVE THE MICROTYPE PACKAGE". You can't identify the problematic font if it is still  there.

Comment: I uninstalled the package but I got still the Error:

Comment: ! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable
fonts.
<argument> ...shipout:D \box_use:N \l_shipout_box
l.99 \include{./Kapitel/Einleitung}
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
36123 strings out of 479799
765502 string characters out of 2869247
1258530 words of memory out of 3000000
52331 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
567464 words of font info for 105 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
112i,20n,113p,10643b,1083s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
! ==> Fatal error occu